# PHP autentication via MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problems with login verification. The connection runs great, but it always shows else echo.. userrname and password name from the form are right..

```
 <?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="root"; // Mysql password
$db_name="login"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['codiceF'];
$mypassword=$_POST['codiceA'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM '$tbl_name' WHERE 'id' = '$myusername' and 'cf' = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$num_rows = $values['total'];

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($num_rows==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:/pages/index.html");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

I change mysql fuctions with mysqli, anyway this doesn't work :(

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="root"; // Mysql password
$db_name="login"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name") or die("cannot connect");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['codiceF'];
$mypassword=$_POST['codiceA'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM '$tbl_name' WHERE 'id' = '$myusername' and 'cf' = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

$values = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$num_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($num_rows==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:/pages/index.html");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: I know that this is not a part of your real problem, but please, use `mysqli` functions instead of `mysql`. The latter one is insecure, obsolete and will soon be removed from the future versions of PHP.

Comment: you have quite a few syntax errors and using a deprecated sessions function. checking for errors would signal those

Comment: @Arkoudinos sorry what's mysqli? i'm a beginner...

Comment: @Arkoudinos all right... i found out ;) anyway now seems to be some errors with connection. thanks

Comment: lament.  Why do beginners try to write security software? They rarely come close to getting it right, and the results just encourage script kiddies and other lamer wannabe cyber criminals. Please read this.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-php-renewed_2/index.html

Comment: @OllieJones How would you define "security" in software? For example, sanitizing user input is one (basic) security practice when writing software. Using prepared statements is another one, maybe a little more complicated. It's better for a beginner to be completely unaware of these practices?

Comment: @Arkoudinos, you're mentioning "secure software." Of course people should learn that stuff.  I'm talking about the software implementing such things as password verification. The naive example presented by the OQ in this question was grossly insecure a decade ago. Security software is hard to get right.

Comment: @OllieJones You're right. I didn't pay the proper attention to what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the Dbs structure that you are following but making a guess try

```
$num_rows = sizeof($values);
```

instead of the code that you wrote currently.
Or alternatively attach the output of

```
var_dump($values)
```

for better debugging of the code.

Comment: please post the output of var_dump($values)

Comment: `NULL Wrong Username or Password`

Comment: I just saw a comment above that you found out. Is your question resolved or there are still some issues. If yes try with correct username and password then give me a dump on $values and the final query that is being executed

Comment: no, it doesn't work yet..advice? i don't understand what's wrong!

Comment: echo $sql query here when you post correct username and password

Comment: I posted correcte user and pwd.. but nothing, always `NULL Wrong Username or Password`

Comment: check database if the entries are saved. I can only think of some error in database

Comment: Yes, they are saved..

 1 num int(11)   No  Nessuno AUTO_INCREMENT 

 2 id varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci  No  

 3 cf varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci  No

Comment: I found a error_log file, look at this: 
1) PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /pages/verify.php on line 19
2) PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /pages/verify.php on line 20
3) PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /pages/verify.php on line 24
4) PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /pages/verify.php on line 24

Comment: 5) PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /pages/verify.php on line 25
6) PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /pages/verify.php on line 25
7) PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /pages/verify.php on line 27
8) PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /pages/verify.php:28) in /pages/verify.php on line 44

Comment: for the error 1 follow this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php .

Comment: infact looking at all the errors i just noticed that you are not saving any link. have a look at this example to know exactly what went wrong http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#example-1758 focus on $link variable in the example which is absent from your code

Comment: No errors right now, but still `NULL` result from research in db

Comment: Again error, only one: PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /pages/verify.php on line 33

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$num_rows = $values['total'];
```

Use

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

So your code should look like

```
...
// Connect to server and select databse.
$link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name") or die("cannot connect");

...
...
...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM '$tbl_name' WHERE 'id' = '$myusername' and 'cf' = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$values = mysqli_fetch_assoc($link, $result);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($link, $result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($num_rows==1){
...
```

Comment: are you sure your query is correct? try to echo `$sql` and run it on a MySQL console and post the result

Comment: here the error, PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given - i don't know what to fix..

Comment: i've edited my answer. your code uses `mysqli_stmt_num_rows` whereas the warning you've posted says `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: thanks, anyway two errors: 1)PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given 
2) PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: i see, you need to save the link returned by mysqli_connect and use that as a parameter in the remaining mysqli_* functions. answer updated